# Convert a vector<int> to string with fmt library

Tags: c++, fmt

How to remove [] from the output?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fmt/format.h>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>

int main () {
    std::vector<int> v = {1,2,3};
    std::string s = fmt::format("{}", v);
    std::cout << s << '\n'; // output : [1, 2, 3]
    return 0;
}
```

how to remove '[' and ']' in output for the above code and only print : 1, 2, 3

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: `std::cout << s.substr(1, s.size()-2) << '\n';`

Comment: I am not familiar with fmt, however, it seems that the prefix `{` and postfix `}` are [hardcoded in `ranges.h` header](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/blob/master/include/fmt/ranges.h#L40).

Comment: @CinCout: This can't be an XY problem. The key aspect of an "XY problem" is that the "Y" is a strange or unusual problem. There's nothing strange or unusual about this question.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I quote the [fmt api](https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#_CPPv2N3fmt4joinERR5Range11string_view):

```cpp
#include <fmt/ranges.h>

std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3};
fmt::print("{}", fmt::join(v, ", "));
// Output: "1, 2, 3"
```